# iOS 11 crash when save to coredata using NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios11

An ios11 application is crashing while saving to core data with a below exception, it is working fine in iOS10 and below.

> Assertion failed: (moreParameters->mostRecentEntry == CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(stack, stackCount - 1)), function NSKeyValuePopPendingNotificationPerThread, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1444.12/EO.subproj/NSKeyValueObserving.m, line 933.

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
                        NSError *saveErr = nil;
                        if (![context save:&saveErr]) {
                            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", saveErr, [saveErr localizedDescription]);
                        }  
}];
```

crash happening at if (![context save:&saveErr])

Below is NSManagedObject:

```
<ContentLanguage: 0x60000009f8b0> (entity: ContentLanguage; id: 0xd0000000000c0006 x-coredata://B53C7782-1231-4DB9-8579-77BFC31ADDA9/ContentLanguage/p3 ; data: {
displayName = "T\U00fcrk\U00e7e";
langId = tr;
relationship = "<relationship fault: 0x60400023c9e0 'relationship'>";
settings = nil;
user = "0xd000000000040002 x-coredata://B53C7782-1231-4DB9-8579-77BFC31ADDA9/User/p1";
})
```

[ContentLanguage Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU5vC.png)

Comment: I am noticing the same crash, and then a failure to save object crash.

Comment: @Siriss same crash your getting or different?

Comment: @harishkotagiri were you able to resolve this? I am having issues with core data since iOS 11, but haven't found much info on core data changes  to iOS update

Comment: @Matt My issue is not with core data, it is KVO pattern issue